# Same PC Computer Name listed with 2 different IPs on the DHCP server

Tags: windows, networking, windows-server-2008-r2, hostname, dhcp-server

Is it normal for the same computer hostname to have 2 different IPs listed in the DHCP server?

We have a Win 2008 R2 DC in a predominately Windows 7 production environment and I've noticed several instances of identical computer hostnames with 2 different ip addresses. From what I understand, you cannot join a new computer to a domain by using an existing hostname, so why the different ip addresses? What's the best practice to resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A single host can have multiple active IPs and this is what you are seeing. You are not seeing two hosts with the same name*.
What you are seeing is a single host taking 1 or more IPs. More than likely this is due to a computer being on wireless and lan at the same time, or have two lans, or the ip renewed or changed before the old lease expired.

*It is possible to have hosts named the same on a network. Domains will not let them have the same name but if they are in different domains or in workgroups the names can be the same.

Comment: You are right. It's a laptop office so we have users with their machines on wireless and LAN all the time under one domain (small company). One of our users is getting an event id: 4319 source: NetBT which stops her from accessing her shared folders so I'm attempting to track down the cause. I appreciate you answering my question, that brings me one step closer to solving the issue.

Comment: If she is one of the ones with 2 IPs that can be the cause.

Comment: I'm feeling a bit confused now. I thought you said a single host can have 2 IPs in the same domain. Did I miss something?

Comment: @B.Ng that is correct. They CAN, but best practice is just to use a single address. Routing can get temporarily messed up and local DNS caches can get confused.

Comment: I see. How would you recommend I approach this? Would deleting one of the ips resolve the issue?

Comment: Have then either turn off wireless or unplug the lan.